# ReactKonva does not support the type "div"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, konvajs

I need to draw a circle with `ReactKonva` and show a tooltip upon hovering over it. In `React` we need to return one element from `render` method, so I am trying to wrap both the tooltip and `ReactKonva` element inside a `div` - tag but it is giving me an error upon rendering the page:

> Uncaught Error: ReactKonva does not support the type "div"

Here is the code that I have:

```
render() {
return (
  <div>
    <Circle
      x={this.props.x}
      y={this.props.y}
      radius={5}
      fill={this.props.color}
      shadowBlur={5}
      onClick={this.handleClick}
      onMouseOver={this.showTooltip}
      onMouseOut={this.hideTooltip}
    />

  <div style={{ height: 120 visibility: this.state.visibility }}>
        <Popover
            id="popover-basic"
            placement="right"
            positionLeft={200}
            positionTop={50}
            title="Popover right"
        >
        Some data is here
      </Popover>
    </div>
  </div>
);
}
```

What could I do to make it working? I have an idea of substituting all `div` tags for `Layer` but I am not sure.

> Update

If we eliminate all `div` tags and return `Circle` and `Popover` as an array, we still get the same error due to `Popover` presence.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to make it working, but not the way I actually wanted to. Basically I am just passing events two levels up where `ReactKonva` framework is not used and there I am showing the popover.

In `ColoredCircle.jsx`:

```
<Circle
      x={this.props.x}
      y={this.props.y}
      radius={5}
      fill={this.props.color}
      shadowBlur={5}
      onClick={this.handleClick}
-----> onMouseOver={this.props.mouseOverHandler}
-----> onMouseOut={this.props.mouseOutHandler}
    />
```

Then, inside its parent `ExpressionGraph.jsx`:

```
<Stage width={window.innerWidth} height={window.innerHeight}>
    <Layer offsetX={offsetX} offsetY={offsetY}>
      {data.map((neuronArr, idx) => {
          const numOfPoints = neuronArr[0].length;
          const circleColor = cssColors[idx];
          return [...Array(numOfPoints)].map((_, pointIdx) => {
            const factor = 50;
            const x = factor*neuronArr[0][pointIdx];
            const y = -factor*neuronArr[1][pointIdx];
            const key = idx + " " + pointIdx;
            return <ColoredCircle key={key} x={x} y={y} color={circleColor}
------>         mouseOverHandler=
                      {this.props.handleCircleMouseOver} 
------>         mouseOutHandler=
                      {this.props.handleCircleMouseOut}/>
        })
      })}
    </Layer>
  </Stage>
```

Then, in the parent of `ExpressionGraph` I am handling the events:

```
  <ExpressionGraph handleCircleMouseOver={this.handleCircleMouseOver}
          handleCircleMouseOut={this.handleCircleMouseOut}/>
```